# why this code for appscript is not working?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My code allows to move `row` if `col5=Published`. I wanted to add more like- if `col5=Published` or `Deleted` or `Denied` `function` will work. I've tried to use like it

```
var valueToWatch = ("Published","Deleted","Denied");
```

But its not working. It only takes last `string` `Denied` not working for `Published` or `Deleted`

```
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Sheet1";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 5; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = ("Published","Deleted","Denied");
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Sheet2";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```

Comment: There are some picky dudes here who will comment to move your post to codereview.stackexchange and will give you downvote as a gift in general! So before you get a minus vote you might rethink about posting this here! :D

Comment: @Naji actually codereview is for make your code better, stackoverflow to make your code working.

Comment: did not know about code review site

Comment: Well thats what they told me and I got a minus vote for that once! So I always hesitate. I hope @Zils wouldn't!

Comment: wish me a good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like:

```js
//var valueToWatch = ("Published","Deleted","Denied");
var valueToWatch = ['Published', 'Deleted', 'Denied'];
...
if (... && valueToWatch.indexOf(range.getValue()) > -1 && ...) {
   ...
}
...
```

Adjust everything you need in your code.